# How to relate a number to the verb "derive"

Tags: integration, derivatives, terminology

Consider:

> By integrating R(r) out to the location of the first minimum, the coordination number for the first solvation shell **is derived 5.4**.

I am not sure about the bold part because 5.4 was immediately appeared after *is derived*. I am not sure about "X is derived N", maybe it is *... is derived **as** 5.4*, right? Generally I can't get the pattern or structure for using a number like that.

Is it correct? what is the structure or pattern? What are other alternatives to relate a number to the result of an operation like integration?

Comment: What is the source of your quotation? Unattributed quotation is bad.

Comment: @bof I am proofreading the paper of someone, I don't know what has been his source.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with what you said. "... the solvation shell is derived *as* $5.4$".

You can use other verbs such as "calculated," I suppose.

".. is calculated to be $5.4$" and  "is calculated as $5.4$" work.